# Car jerks if I keep gas pressed at a particular level

Tags: mitsubishi, intermittent-problems, outlander

I have a Mitsubishi Outlander 2009, BSY engine Volkswagen 2.0 DI-D Diesel.
Recently I changed the EGR Valve because it was clogged up, and it has previously thrown errors about it, but there has never been an indicator lit up to show any problems.

Now, when I keep the gas pressed at a certain level, at speeds between 50-60km/h depending on the gear, and I keep it there to maintain the speed, there is this "sweetspot" for lack of a better word, that when I hit it, the car jerks back and forth as if I'm releasing the gas and then pressing on it again in a quick succession. Once this starts happening, and I apply more gas, the car speeds up normally, or if I let go of the gas, it decelerates normally.

I'm not sure if this started happening as a result of me changing the EGR valve, or it happened before but it less intensity or frequency that I haven't paid attention to it, but if memory serves me right there has been instances when the same happened before the change, just not as regular as they're occurring now.

The computer is not showing any errors, so I have no idea where to even start.
I have to note that in my country the mechanics are not that good, and most aren't even equipped with proper gear to diagnose cars so I'm left to it on my own, changing parts the computer tells me are bad.

That's how I handled all repairs so far. I just bring them the pieces and they change them, but I have to find the problem on my own unless I want to pay insane amount of money, it's cheaper to just buy a new part, at least you'll have a new part in your car...

The car is old, and I bought it second hand.

Any help, is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!